# Android sound seekbar/chart like telegram

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I need to make this chart that works like seekbar. In telegram when you send voice message to someone, that person can play that voice and have this kind of seekbar.

I was looking for some dependencies but I found only 
[this](https://github.com/gauravk95/audio-visualizer-android) and [this](https://github.com/GautamChibde/android-audio-visualizer) and they are animating sound.

I need some guidelines how to make this kind of view. If you have any guide, tutorial or anything please let me know, thanks.

[image]